# String comparison using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

my aryContacts contains test_tech,test,abc_tech,testing,hh_techvedika

```
 NSArray *arrSeperated = [[[aryContacts objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"contactName"]componentsSeparatedByString:@“_”];
    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName CONTAINS [cd]%@",[arrSeperated objectAtIndex:0]];
         NSArray    *arrContacts1 = [aryContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSPredicate *predicate1 =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName CONTAINS [cd]%@",[arrSeperated objectAtIndex:1]];
            NSArray    *arrContacts2 = [aryContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate1];
```

**result**: arrContacts1 contains test_tech,test,testing
**expected**: arrContacts1 contains test_tech,test

**result**: arrContacts2 contains test_tech,abc_tech,hh_techvedika
**expected**: arrContacts2 contains test_tech,abc_tech

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName BEGINSWITH [cd]%@", [[arrTempContacts objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"contactName"]];
NSArray *arrContacts = [arrTempContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

let me know it is working or not!!!!

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Looks promising hence get 10.

Comment: Its failing when the input is test,test_sample ,testing_sample expected result is test,sample. Will divide array using special characters(test and sample are two different words in this case)

Comment: check my updated answer. replace "c" in BEGINSWITH [c] with "cd".Please check it...

Comment: array contains test_sample,test,abc_sample,testing
I am dividing the string based on special characters by using componentsSeparatedByString . i want the result as test,sample

Comment: but you told that you want result like this: test, test_sample, test_s.You have posted expected result in your question. Please be sure what you want to do??

Comment: Ok this is the array test_sample,test,abc_sample,testing and expected result is test, sample .I am using predicate by dividing string based on special characters.

Comment: Basically use of NSPredicate is to search particular sub string from string or to compare 2 objects. If you want to separate string then you can do it using componentsSeparatedByString

Comment: yes..aryContacts contains test_tech,test,abc_tech,testing,hh_techvedika
  NSArray *arrSeperated = [[[aryContacts objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"contactName"]componentsSeparatedByString:@“_”];NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName CONTAINS [cd]%@",[arrSeperated objectAtIndex:0]]; NSArray *arrContacts1 = [aryContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];NSPredicate *predicate1 =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"contactName CONTAINS [cd]%@",[arrSeperated objectAtIndex:1]]; NSArray *arrContacts2 = [aryContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate1];

Comment: **result**: arrContacts1 contains test_tech,test,testing
**expected**: arrContacts1 contains test_tech,test
**result**: arrContacts2 contains test_tech,abc_tech,hh_techvedika
**expected**: arrContacts2 contains test_tech,abc_tech